# Figure placement without the next section being forced on a new page

Tags: positioning

I am trying to include an image, which I want within the section in which it is referred to. When I try to use the `\FloatBarrier` command, the figure stays within the section, however the next section goes on a new page thus leaving a lot of blank space after the figure, before the next section starts. Is there a way to keep a figure within the required section and also not force the next section to a new page? (I mean, is there a command opposite to `\clearpage?`)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.